# Add tooltips for custom commands to List Items’ context menu

Tags: listview, sharepoint, tooltip, spfx

we are using SharePoint Framework Extensions: Command Set to add custom commands to contextual menu and toolbar.

There are no issue to add commands whereas **we faced an issue how to add tooltips to custom commands.**

*1. our .manifest.json file content looks like that:*

```
 {
      "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx/command-set-extension-manifest.schema.json",
      "id": "...",
      "alias": "DocumentLibraryCommandSet",
      "componentType": "Extension",
      "extensionType": "ListViewCommandSet",
      "requiresCustomScript": false,
      "items": {
        "SomeId": {
          "title": {
            "default": "some name"
          },
          "iconImageUrl": "...",
          "type": "command"
        },
    }
}
```

*2. we added classs which extends 'BaseListViewCommandSet' and overrided: onInit, onListViewUpdated, onExecute.*

```
export default class xxxtLibraryCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<xxx> {

    @override
    public onInit(): Promise<void> {
        return xxx;
    }

    @override
    public onListViewUpdated()
       xxx
    }

    @override
    public onExecute(xxx): void {
       xxx
    }
```

*3. classes*

- 'BaseListViewCommandSet' extends 'BaseExtension', there is 'context:
  ListViewCommandSetContext'
- 'ListViewCommandSetContext' has 'manifest:ICommandSetExtensionManifest'
- here are 'items' with 'ICommandDefinition' type
  items: { [itemId: string]: ICommandDefinition; };

**and 'ICommandDefinition' has only 4 fields**

(I'm not able to add, for example desctiption or tooltip here)

```
export interface ICommandDefinition {
    title: ILocalizedString;
    type: 'command';
    ariaLabel?: ILocalizedString;
    iconImageUrl?: string;
}
```

**Could anybody to give a hint how to add tooltips to custom commands?**